# readlink for Git symrefs: API equivalent of "cat .git/HEAD"

Tags: git

This should be simple, but I can't seem to find it; what is the Git command equivalent for:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

That is, I simply want the ref to which this symref points. Both git-show-ref and git-symbolic-ref seem to always dereference.

Thanks!

UPDATE: OK, that was phenomenally stupid... I was tripped up by my own command aliases for show-ref and symbolic-ref. :( Yes, as pointed out, git symbolic-ref does exactly what I thought it should. Figures; I was sure this had worked for me in the past, and indeed it had. Thanks!

Comment: `git symbolic-ref HEAD` does not dereference it. What are you trying?

Comment: I was trying the wrong thing, thanks to my own goofed-up command aliases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Um, `git symbolic-ref HEAD` should do exactly what you want.

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

Note that if you are currently in a detached HEAD state, it *will* give you a hash, because that's what `HEAD` is pointing at.